# NestJS background process which fetches data in 5 parallel actions

Tags: javascript, async-await, synchronization, nestjs

I am working on a NestJS API which receives some article codes and saves them in a DB with status as `queue` and then i want to build a background process which searches for articles with `queue` status and fetches a website with that code and fills in the information about that article ID.

I want it to fetch codes in 5 parallel routines, each one should get a new code from the list as soon as it finished fetching the current code.

The way it's built right now, it gets 5 codes and uses `Promise.all` but what i don't like on this approach is that if one of the await is significantly slower than the other, they all way for the slowest one.

```
const promiseResult = await Promise.all(promiseList);
```

Which approach is the best one for me to learn in order to achieve what i am planning to do?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you do your job when all the promises are fulfilled. You are correct when you say that you wait for the slowest one, as this is exactly what `await Promise.all(promiseList)` does.

Now you need to ask yourself the question whether you are able to process the quicker promises while you await for the slowest one. If so, then you can iterate your promises and define a [.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) for them:

```
for (let promise of promiseList) {
    promise.then((value) => {
        //Do something
    });
}
```

This way all your promises have a `then` handler for the case when the promise is fulfilled and your Javascript flows normally, without waiting for any of the promises. Once each promise is fulfilled, the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) will detect that an event happened and call your callback function (in the case of the example above, the arrow function inside the `then` call).

Note that the `then` callback should never assume that the other promises were also completed, but that shouldn't be a problem in your case, because you want to work when your promise list was only partially completed as well.

Comment: i read something about workers and another thing about Bull & Redis queue.. do you think one of those approaches fits better than async - await ? i don't mind learning new stuff if it helps me long term

Comment: @PacuraruDaniel service workers is Javascript's way to do some threading. In your case this does not really seem to be necessary, since your asynchronous promises take time indeed, but they are not blocking you if you do not synchronize `.all()`. You have some callback functions for the case when the promise was fulfilled. If those callback functions are time-consuming, then you might consider the use of service workers, but this is probably not the case. Using queues make sense in many cases, but in your case you want your promises to perform their operation in parallel.

Comment: @PacuraruDaniel Doing things in parallel is the antithesis of queuing them. So, it very much seems that the best thing you can do to cope with your problem is to iterate the promises and add a `.then()` to them. You can of course create libraries and/or classes that would be reusable if you see any possibility that your current code could be useful later in different, but similar scenarios. If my answer led you to the solution, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: @LajosArpad - Queues are a fundamental component of parallel processing...